# Make Docker image error

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm actually trying to make a docker image by running the command make docker. I have a Makefile, but this is what appears in the terminal, I'm using Debian 386 (32 bit).

```
administrator@debian:~/work/src/github.com/TheThingsNetwork/ttn$ make docker
docker build -t thethingsnetwork/ttn -f Dockerfile .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 71.14 MB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 
Step 0 : FROM alpine
 ---> 65312f45ea0c
Step 1 : RUN apk --update --no-cache add ca-certificates
 ---> Running in b6afead07718
exec format error
INFO[0016] [8] System error: exec format error          
Makefile:175: recipe for target 'docker' failed
make: *** [docker] Error 1
```

Comment: can you reformat it for a bit?

Comment: can you run `uname -a`?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're trying to use a 64bit base image on a 32bit host OS. Try `FROM armhf/alpine` instead. This will use an [Alpine image compiled for ARM](https://hub.docker.com/r/armhf/alpine/).